# Why is Snowflake attempting to use POST for an External Function to him my AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-api-gateway

I followed a barebones example in Snowflake to setup an external function inside of Snowflake that can execute a API Gateway in my AWS Account.

Everything is 100% working outside the fact that Snowflake is attempting to POST versus GET, which causes an error with my resource policy on the API Gateway. I tested with a POST route and all works great.

Error:

```
 Request failed for external function SEND_REMINDER_EMAIL_EXTERNAL_FUNCTION with remote service error: 403 '{"Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::####:assumed-role/SnowflakeExternalFunctionRole/snowflake is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:xx-xxxx-1:********xxxx:xxxx/v1/POST/sendemail"}'
```

Integration:

```
create or replace api integration send_email_api_integration
    api_provider = aws_api_gateway
    api_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/SnowflakeExternalFunctionRole'
    enabled = true
    api_allowed_prefixes = ('https://xxxxx.execute-api.xx-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com/v1/sendemail');
```

The code for my external function is here:

```
create or replace external function xxxxx.send_reminder_email_external_function
    ()
    returns variant
    api_integration = send_email_api_integration
    as 'https://xxxx.execute-api.xx-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com/v1/sendemail';
```

Why would Snowflake default to POST versus GET? Is there anyway for it force a GET?

Comment: No, you can’t force Snowflake to use GET instead of POST. The process it uses is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.

Comment: Because the function needs to be sent data, and GET do not allow for data, only encoded in the URL which is not secure. Thus a POST is used.